# Javascript IE Event

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, events, dom-events

This works in Firefox, but not IE. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
  var form = document.getElementById('theform')
    /* create the event handler */
    form.gen.onclick = function( evt ) {
        var f = evt.target.form
        var y = f.year.value
        var m = f.month.value
        genCalendar( document, y, m, 'theCalendar' )
    }
```

Comment: you should end statements with `;` - the implicit `;` at line endings is a fallback mechanism and I'd consider using it bad practice (other's may disagree)

Answer (score 15):

To get the target of an event in both standards compliant browsers and IE, use

```
var target = evt ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement;
```

There's an [overview of the different properties of event objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Migrate_apps_from_Internet_Explorer_to_Mozilla#section_26) at MDC.

Comment: I think it should be: `var target = evt.target ? evt.target : window.event.srcElement;`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, IE does not pass the event object as a parameter. Try this:

```
var form = document.getElementById('theform')
  /* create the event handler */
  form.gen.onclick = function( evt ) {
    if(!evt)
      evt = window.event;
    var f = evt.target.form
    var y = f.year.value
    var m = f.month.value
    genCalendar( document, y, m, 'theCalendar' )
}
```

Or better yet, use a cross-browser library, like [Prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org) or [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

Comment: also, you'll have to use `.srcElement` instead of `.target` in IE

Answer (score 1):

- When does this script run?  You might have to run this script onload, after the DOM is fully loaded

```
<script>

function go()
{
  alert('dom is loaded:  register event handlers now') ;
}

</script>

<body onload=" go(); ">



</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is why you should consider using a javascript library such as jquery, YUI, or prototype. These libraries abstract away the browser based differences which simplifies your coding.

Answer (score 0):

From my own searching the most sucessful was this

```
function clickHandler(e){
 var elem, evt = e ? e:event;
 if (evt.srcElement)  elem = evt.srcElement;
 else if (evt.target) elem = evt.target;

 alert (''
  +'You clicked the following HTML element: \n <'
  +elem.tagName.toUpperCase()
  +'>'
 )
 return true;
}

document.onclick=clickHandler;
```

Sourced from ther very helpful and explanatory http://www.javascripter.net/faq/eventtargetsrcelement.htm